# LOOP instruction in a program

Tags: assembly, x86

I cannot understand why if i use loop instruction the program doesn't work good. CX is 3 and normally it should go in "repeta" 3 times, but it works just first time and than the program is finished.

```
;2. Se da un sir de dublucuvinte. Sa se ordoneze descrescator sirul cuvintelor inferioare ale acestor dublucuvinte. Cuvintele superioare raman neschimbate.
;Ex: dandu-se: sir DD 12345678h 1256ABCDh, 12AB4344h 
;rezultatul va fi 1234ABCDh, 12565678h, 12AB4344h.

assume cs: code, ds:data

data segment
sir dd 12340004h, 12560007h, 12AB0005h,12340009h
l equ ($-sir)/4
data ends

code segment
start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
mov si,offset sir
mov cx,l-1
repeta:
mov di,si
add di,4
do:
  mov ax,word ptr [di]
  mov bx, word ptr [si]
  cmp word ptr [si],ax 
  ja final
  movsw
  sub di,2
  sub si,2
  mov word ptr [si],ax
  final:
       add di,4
       cmp di,l*4-1
       jl do
       add si,4
       loop repeta
 ;dec cx
 ;cmp cx,0
 ;jne repeta
 mov ax,4c00h
 int 21h
 code ends
 end start
```

Comment: I just ran your code and it repeated 3 times. What compiler are you using? How do you watch CX value?

Comment: dosbbox could you recommend me another one? with CPU I watch the CX value

Comment: I can recommend you this one = https://sourceforge.net/projects/guitasm8086/, but you should find out what's wrong with your current compiler (are you sure this is the code you are running?).

Comment: yes this is the code and in my computer it doesn;t work :(

Comment: I don;t know what to do to make it works...

Comment: Download the compiler I recommended you and run your code.

Comment: Ok thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A good reason why this program could malfunction and why it could *seem* that it doesn't iterate 3 times is, if the direction flag DF were set. The `movsw` depends on the DF=0.
  Either:

  - Write `cld` and keep using `movsw`
  - Write `mov word ptr [di], bx` instead of the trio `movsw` `sub di,2` `sub si,2`
    The fact that your code already had an unused `mov bx, word ptr [si]` instruction led to this.
- `DI` represents an address. In your program you should treat it as unsigned.
  Also `l*4-1` is no better than `l*4`.

  ```
  add     di, 4
  cmp     di, l*4
  jb      do
  ```